# Using Shell Script to create a for loop which passes a parameter to a python function

Tags: python, shell

I have some shell script that I am trying to make that looks like this:

```
YEAR[1]="2015"
YEAR[2]="2020"
YEAR[3]="2025"
YEAR[4]="2030"

for i in "${YEAR[@]}"
do
  Python -c "some function( *YEAR*, parameter2, parameter3 )"
done
```

I already created a function in python that has a parameter YEAR, which I would like the shell script to loop through for each year and make some calculations. But I have no idea how I can pass "i" into the YEAR parameter.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: why don't you simply use python for the whole task?

Comment: The reason why I dont use python for the whole task is because I am creating this script so I can run on multiple machines. I will need to modify other parameters such as parameter2 and parameter3 for each model run. I need this flexibility.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your reasoning. the python code doesn't have to be a single file.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "some_function( $i, parameter2, parameter3 )"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that didn't work either

Comment: that's because you haven't told us the (whole) truth.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$i` work? Or you can test `eval Python -c "some function( $i, parameter2, parameter3 )"`

Comment: Thanks for your response but neither of those worked.

Comment: I build a little script, it works fine. I can't understand what problem you have.

`#!/bin/bash
YEAR[1]="2015"
YEAR[2]="2020"
YEAR[3]="2025"
YEAR[4]="2030"
for i in "${YEAR[@]}"
do
      python -c "print max( $i, 2014, 2024 )"
done`

Answer (score 0):

Add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the shell script and use Python syntax in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
years = [2015, 2020, 2025, 2030] # or range(2015, 2031, 5)
for y in years:
    some_function(y, "parameter2", "parameter3")
```

Comment: Yes, but I still need to run shell code, can I run both codes in the same script? I guess I could just create another python function that loops through the functions automatically so I don't have to loop in shell???

Comment: @AllenLee: yes, you can run shell code from Python (in a child process) and vice versa.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do but I am unfamiliar with the syntax to put pass shell code into python code.

Comment: In Python: `from subprocess import call; rc = call(r"""put multiline shell code here""", shell=True)`. And yes, you can *"loop through the functions automatically"* in Python (you could [update your question to include that part of your shell code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22398935/edit))

Comment: Sorry I take my first comment back. I thought about it and I do need to write it in shell because I am sending this script to remote machines that will a model (for years 2015-2030) but I also need to change the parameters if that makes sense. Thats why I prefer to call python from shell, not the other way around

Comment: @AllenLee: I do not understand. If you need to call `python` from the shell script anyway, what is the issue with using it as a more clean programming language for stuff like loops?